# Best way to train a model in keras r

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

**Overview**

I'm not new to R but am very new to machine learning.

For work I collect data by writing on a datasheet printed on waterproof paper which I then have to transcribe to the database manually. This takes a long time at the end of a long day and is a process prone to mistakes.

The entire datasheet is shown below

[image: Image showing the entire datasheet used]

What I would like to do is simply take a photo of the sheet and have keras read it and input the results into a database

And the section of the datasheet that I am interested in getting Keras to read is shown here

[image]

Each row of the datasheet represents what species of coral was found and each column represents what transect it was found on ie 7 Acroppora was found on T1

Each of these cells are given a unique entry in the database in a format similar to this which would show how the Acropora row is recorded

[image]

For each datasheet that we have entered in the past (probably somewhere between 1000 and 2500) there are corresponding database entries which can be exported to csv and linked to each datasheet

Ultimately, what I would like to do is simply take a photo of the sheet and have keras read the part I'm interested in (shown in second image) and input the results into a CSV in a similar format shown in the third image

**The questions**

What I've been thinking about is getting it to identify the borders of the parts of the datasheet I'm interested in (shown in the second image) and extract it. This would mean that I could then put in coordinates for each cell, ie Acropora T1 (as shown in the image below) and identify the number counted in that cell and export it to a database

[image]

Does this process sound possible? If so, would anyone know of any examples I could look up or even what you would call this process so I can look it up

Otherwise I was thinking about scanning each sheet as a whole (As shown in the first image) and simply training from that, however I feel that would be more prone to errors

I really hope this makes sense and would very much appreciate any help and/or suggestions either specifically to the questions that I asked or about my project in general

Comment: The question as it stands "scares" away people. Questions with less words but sample data and sample code plus expected output get more traffic. Use `dput(head(df,20))` to provide data not images. I can for instance not access the attached images.

Comment: @NelsonGon How does one show such images then when it is about image processing ? Is there any alternative ? I find this question interesting.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan sorry. I couldn't see the images when I first wrote here. I however still think the question could be summarized.

Comment: Hey @NelsonGon, I too am a fan of good writing and I'm sure this could've been written in a more concise fashion, however being that I am in unfamiliar territory I wasn't sure how. To answer your original comment , I haven't started coding for this yet I was hoping to get some insight on how to approach the problem, if you have any questions let me know otherwise I'd be appreciative of any guidance

Comment: The code I have shown at the end of the answer prints correct values.

Answer (score 1):

This uses OpenCV and Python.

According to the chapter on '[Hough Line Transform](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)' you could detect lines like this.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('D:/Books/lines1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('D:/Books/edges.jpg',edges)
```

[image]

But based on my simple research I think counting is possible using code like this.

More knowledge of OpenCV is required at this stage. I think this is just dilating and the borders of the lines are more pronounced.

```
img = cv2.imread('D:/Books/lines1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('D:/Books/edges.jpg',edges)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (4, 4))

dilated_Edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=1)
cv2.imwrite("D:/Books/dilated_Edges.jpg", dilated_Edges);

lines = cv2.HoughLines(image=dilated_Edges,rho=1,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100)

print( len(lines))
```

[image]

This prints `8` for me which isn't correct.

> I pursued this and this code is based on help from the OpenCV forum(Suleyman TURKMEN).

Images I tested with are these. Prints the correct count.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import cv2
import math

img = cv2.imread('D:/Books/lines1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

ret,bw = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("bw", bw)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 2))
eroded_Edges = cv2.erode(bw, kernel, iterations=3)

dilated_Edges = cv2.dilate(eroded_Edges, kernel, iterations=4)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_Edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

print (len(contours) , " horizontal lines")

cv2.imshow("vertical lines", eroded_Edges)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 5))
eroded_Edges = cv2.erode(bw, kernel, iterations=3)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(eroded_Edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

print (len(contours) , " vertical lines")

cv2.imshow("horizontal lines", eroded_Edges)

cv2.waitKey()
```